# How to change the way a single value is represented from a bar to a line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with a dataset that I found on wikipedia regarding the nutritional content of staple grains.  I scraped the data table using the rvest package and created the graphic shown below

[image: Nutrient Content of Major Staple Foods]

It was pointed out to me that perhaps it might be better to represent the "Recommended Dietary Allowance"(RDA) with a vertical line as opposed to a bar.

1)  How to a create the separate vertical line representing "Recommended Dietary Allowance"?

The code used to create the graphic is below:  I am not sure on whether I should include the code used to gather and wrangle the data.  Please let me know if that would help.

```
ggplot(grain.nut, aes(grain, nutrients, fill = grain)) +
  facet_wrap(~ nutrient.component., scales = "free") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Nutrient Content of Major Staple Foods per 100 gram Portion",
       caption = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staple_food#Nutritional_content") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 30, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.80,0.05), legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.84)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#e70000",
                               "#204bcc",
                               "#68ca3b",
                               "#fe9bff",
                               "#518901",
                               "#de0890",
                               "#fcba4c",
                               "#292c7a",
                               "#e69067",
                               "#79b5ff",
                               "#68272d",
                               "#c9cb6c"))
```

I have tried using geom_vline as well as geom_hline.  But I think my problem is the way I am trying to call the value for RDA via levels(grain.nut$grain)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lohPd.png), the output of which is "Recommended Dietary Allowance".

```
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = levels(grain.nut$grain)[1]))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `geom_linerange` or `geom_pointrange`.

First the data:

```
library("rvest")
library(tidyverse)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staple_food"
nutrient <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]') %>%
  html_table()
```

get the correct order of levels for discrete scale:

```
lev = levels(as.factor(z$grain))[c(1:4,6:12, 5)]
```

The plot:

```
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = nutrient[[1]] %>%
                    as.tibble() %>%
                    gather(grain, value, 2:ncol(.)) %>%
                    filter(grain!="RDA") %>%
                    mutate(nutrient = `Nutrient component:`,
                           value = as.numeric(value)), aes(grain, value, fill = grain),  position = "dodge")+
  geom_pointrange(data = nutrient[[1]] %>%
                   as.tibble() %>%
                   gather(grain, value, 2:ncol(.)) %>%
                   filter(grain=="RDA") %>%
                   mutate(nutrient = `Nutrient component:`,
                          value = as.numeric(value)), aes(x = grain, ymin = 0, ymax = value, y = value, color = grain), size = 0.3, show.legend = F)+
  facet_wrap(~ nutrient, scales = "free") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = lev) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Nutrient Content of Major Staple Foods per 100 gram Portion",
       caption = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staple_food#Nutritional_content") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 30, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.80,0.05), legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.84)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#e70000",
                               "#204bcc",
                               "#68ca3b",
                               "#fe9bff",
                               "#518901",
                               "#de0890",
                               "#fcba4c",
                               "#292c7a",
                               "#e69067",
                               "#79b5ff",
                               "#68272d",
                               "#c9cb6c"))
```

[image]

Basically two layers are used with different data: geom_col with data without RDA and geom_pointrange for data with only RDA. And the order is changed in scale_x_discrete to match the lev object.

If you do not like the points use geom_linerange and omit the y in he aes call

or did u mean this?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = nutrient[[1]] %>%
             as.tibble() %>%
             gather(grain, value, 2:ncol(.)) %>%
             filter(grain!="RDA") %>%
             mutate(nutrient = `Nutrient component:`,
                    value = as.numeric(value)), aes(grain, value, fill = grain),  position = "dodge")+
  geom_hline(data = nutrient[[1]] %>%
                    as.tibble() %>%
                    gather(grain, value, 2:ncol(.)) %>%
                    filter(grain=="RDA") %>%
                    mutate(nutrient = `Nutrient component:`,
                           value = as.numeric(value)), aes(yintercept = value), show.legend = F)+
  facet_wrap(~ nutrient, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Nutrient Content of Major Staple Foods per 100 gram Portion",
       caption = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staple_food#Nutritional_content") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 30, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.80,0.05), legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.84)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#e70000",
                               "#204bcc",
                               "#68ca3b",
                               "#fe9bff",
                               "#518901",
                               "#de0890",
                               "#fcba4c",
                               "#292c7a",
                               "#e69067",
                               "#79b5ff",
                               "#68272d",
                               "#c9cb6c"))
```

[image]

Comment: The second graph you created is exactly the solution I am looking for.  Thank you!